# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable on lists of different sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to print the common items in two list of lists with different sizes, but I am getting the following error. `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

These are the lists

```py
lst1 = [[1234, John Paul, New York], [4567, Jude Law, London],[7891, Rick Ross, Miami]]
lst2 = [[1234, John Paul, New York], [7891, Rick Ross, Miami]]
```

This is my function which is looping through the list and trying to find the common items and put them into a new list.

```py
lst1 = [[1234, John Paul, New York], [4567, Jude Law, London],[7891, Rick Ross, Miami]]
lst2 = [[1234, John Paul, New York], [7891, Rick Ross, Miami]]
list = []
min_lengh = min(len(lst1), len(lst2))
max_lengh = max(len(lst1), len(lst2))

for i in range(max_lengh):
    if lst1[i[0] % min_lengh] == lst2[i[0] % min_lengh]:
        list.append(i % min_lengh)
return list
```

So I am checking if the first items in the list match, if they do then add them to the list.

The line which is throwing the error is this.

```
if lst1[i[0] % min_lengh] == lst2[i[0] % min_lengh]:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, lst1)) & set(map(tuple, lst2))))`

Comment: @ThePyGuy I understand you're going for the copy-editor badge, but please make edits that are actually helpful. Replacing code blocks with code fences is not a significant edit. Editing a question it bumps it to the front page.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is not an element in the list, it's an index: `0`, `1`, `2`, ... So `i[0]` makes no sense.

You probably meant `lst1[i % min_lengh][0]`: first get the sub-list (such as `[1234, John Paul, New York]`), then get the first element from that sub-list (such as `1234`).

Comment: Yes exactly, first get the sub-list and then return the data for the matching id. So in this case the data `1234` @Thomas

Comment: what I am trying to do is fine the common id and check whether the names with the same ID are matching. The issue is that the lists are of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has some issues to run through both the list . here is the working solution

```
lst1 = [[1234, 'John Paul', 'New York'], [4567, 'Jude Law', 'London'],[7891, 'Rick Ross', 'Miami']]
lst2 = [[1234, 'John Paul', 'New York'], [7891, 'Rick Ross', 'Miami']]
list = []
min_lengh = min(len(lst1), len(lst2))
max_lengh = max(len(lst1), len(lst2))

for i in range(max_lengh):
    for j in range(max_lengh):
        if lst1[i % min_lengh] == lst2[j % min_lengh]:
            list.append(lst1[i])
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is set up as the `range` iterator. So it has `int` values like `0, 1, 2...`. So you can't do `i[0]`. That's why you get the error.

I can't make out what the modulo operator is trying to accomplish when comparing two list of lists or why you're checking `i[0]` but you probably meant to use `i` like this instead:

```py
if lst1[i % min_lengh] == lst2[i % min_lengh]:
```

...which you did correctly in your `append` line:

> `list.append(i % min_lengh)`

---

Btw, using `list` as a variable name is a *terrible idea* because it overwrites Python's built-in `list()` function/constructor. So you then can't create a *list* using it. Maybe call it `indexes` or `result`, something meaningful and not clashing with Python's standard library names.

Answer (score 0):

lst1 = [[1234, 'John Paul', 'New York'], [4567, 'Jude Law', 'London'],[7891, 'Rick Ross', 'Miami']]

lst2 = [[1234, 'John Paul', 'New York'], [7891, 'Rick Ross', 'Miami']]

list = [(x) for x in lst1 for y in lst2 if x == y]